# Quick Part problem

Tags: document-library, word, quick-parts

I've got a group of users who have added a quick part into their Word documents in one of their document libraries in MOSS 2007 Enterprise.  This quick part pulls in the FilePath. The library only has major versioning enabled.

For one user on Word 2007, when she tries to update the file path in the footer, it is defaulting to her local file system.

In my Word 2010 and Word 2007 tests, each time I try to update the quick part, either by going into the footer and manually telling it to update or doing the print preview refresh, it updates properly to the server URL.

I assume this is a Word configuration issue. What setting would be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have checked this already, but does she have items saving to her local drafts?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried that and it pulled the server url. I'll double check it.